# Одна функция print в несколько строк

Tags: python, python-3.x

как можно одним вызовом функции print напечатать несколько строк.
что то на подобии вот этого:

```
print("
text
")
```

но так не работает. (и я это знаю, не надо ржать плиз)
гугил по этой теме, везде говорилось про \n

p.s: количество строк, которые мне нужно добавить, превышает 50

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы печатать текст с переводом строк, оберните его в тройные кавычки: `"""..."""`.

Если же использовать кавычки так: `'...'`, то для перевода строки необходимо вставить символ `\n`.

***Пример:***

```py
print("""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit""")

print('===========================================')

print(
    'Mauris est eros, commodo sed tincidunt eget\n'
    'consequat vel ante. Donec porta orci mi'
)
```

***stdout:***

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
===========================================
Mauris est eros, commodo sed tincidunt eget
consequat vel ante. Donec porta orci mi
```

Answer (score 0):

Если мы говорим о python 3, то можно сделать и так:

```
print("a", "b", "c", sep="\n")
```

Вывод

```
a
b
c
```